# Size of browser including scrollbars?

Tags: size, height, width, scrollbar, viewport

Simple question, how do I set up a page overlay (just a semi-transparent black cover) so that it's 100% of the viewport's height and width, **including scrollbars**?

I've already tried:

```
body{
background-image:url(../pictures/background2.png);
background-position:top;
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin:0;
border:0;
height:100%;
}

/*Loading*/
#loadingoverlay {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
filter:alpha(opacity = 80);
top:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:99;
}
```

It only covers the viewport without scrollbars. In other words the moment I scroll down, the content below one screen height doesn't get covered by the overlay.

Obviously this won't work either:

```
/*Loading*/
#loadingoverlay {
position: absolute;
height:9999px;
width:9999px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
filter:alpha(opacity = 80);
top:0;
bottom:0;
z-index:99;
}
```

As that just stretches the viewport into 9999x9999.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is not a part of the "viewport". You're styles and javascript have domain over the viewport but not the scroll bar. You can turn off scroll bars but you can not have an overlay go over it. It's possible to do windowless Flash but that's not an implementation you want.

Comment: You're saying it's impossible to have a simple black overlay, even with jQuery etc if my website's height overflows one screen-height?...

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean now. I thought you wanted to overlay the scrollbars themselves. You can fix that with `position: fixed` on the overlay and modal div. You may want to check out Twitter Bootstrap for it's [modal feature](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Did `position: fixed` answer your question?